# "Вебинар" — есть ли такое слово?

Tags: неологизм

Сейчас появилось много новых слов, которые мне, например, режут слух. "Решебник" вместо "учебника", а еще новое — "вебинар" (сетевой семинар). Есть ли вообще такие слова или это какие-то выкидыши новояза (прошу прощения за резкость)?

Comment: Если Вы эти слова используете, значит, они есть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слово "решебник" тоже восприняла лет так 10 (или уже больше?) как новое. Сейчас его фиксирует орфографический словарь и словарь синонимов. Что удивительно, поиск в словарях на Яндексе выдает ссылку на словарь Ушакова (1940 год). Почему-то сомневаюсь. Может, потому, что больше ни в каком толковом словаре нет. У кого есть бумажная версия, уточните, пожалуйста. Слово "вебинар" активно используется, в русском языке полного соответствия не было, так что, на мой взгляд, это слово нужное. Слово зафиксировано в словаре синонимов. Так что оба слова существуют в современном языке.

Answer (score 1):

> "Решебник" вместо "учебника"

Так это и не вместо. Это разные книги. Учебник учит, а в решебнике готовые ответы-решения. Так что Ваши "выкидыши" режут слух больше.